# How to avoid dismiss alertDialog by tapping on screen and force closing by button in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an alertDialog which has 2 button "STOP" and "CONTINUE" and each of them has a specific function.
I need to force the user to perform one of these function when the alertDialog pop up, and I want to avoid that user tap on screen to dismiss it.
is there a function to avoid dismissing by tapping on screen and force using the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
  ....
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/barrierDismissible.html

Comment: you can also use willPopScope with it to prevent the back button use